# What is the grade of this hadith about praying with lower garment hanging down?

Tags: hadith, salat, authenticity

Narrated Abu Hurairah:

A man was praying with his lower garment hanging down. The Messenger of Allah ﷺ said to him: Go and perform ablution. He then went and performed ablution. He then came and he said: Go and perform ablution. Then a man said to him: Messenger of Allah, what is the matter with you that you commanded him to perform ablution and then you kept silence ? He replied: He was praying while hanging down his lower garments, and Allah does not accept the prayer of a man who hangs down his lower garment.

Sunan Abi Dawood, 4086
Sunan Abi Dawood, Vol. 4, Book of Clothing (Kitab Al-Libas), Hadith 4075
Sunan Abi Dawood, Book of Clothing (Kitab Al-Libas), Hadith 4075

Comment: That hadith specifically was weak according to Al-Albani. However, perhaps your intention was to ask the following question: [Is it necessary for Muslim males to wear cloths that which show up the skin above the ankles?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1895/is-it-necessary-for-muslim-males-to-wear-cloths-that-which-show-up-the-skin-abov)

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn more about how this site works. Thanks for the question and providing the reference.